# "gcloud sql instances create" aborts when given options

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

When I run `gcloud sql instances create testdb1`, I make a database.
When I run `gcloud sql instances create testdb2 --pricing-plan=PER_USE`, I get a python stack trace:

```
DEBUG: operation : None
DEBUG: (gcloud.sql.instances.create) The instance or operation is not in an appropriate state to handle the request.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/scole/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 548, in Execute
    result = args.cmd_func(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/home/scole/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 1124, in Run
    result = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/home/scole/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/sql/util.py", line 229, in Func
    return foo(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/scole/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/sql/tools/instances/create.py", line 206, in Run
    result = sql_client.instances.Insert(instance_resource)
  File "/home/scole/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudapis/sqladmin/v1beta3/sqladmin_v1beta3_client.py", line 401, in Insert
    config, request, global_params=global_params)
  File "/home/scole/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudapis/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 639, in _RunMethod
    return self.ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response)
  File "/home/scole/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudapis/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 645, in ProcessHttpResponse
    self.__ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response))
  File "/home/scole/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudapis/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 528, in __ProcessHttpResponse
    raise exceptions.HttpError.FromResponse(http_response)
HttpException: The instance or operation is not in an appropriate state to handle the request.
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.create) The instance or operation is not in an appropriate state to handle the request.
```

That trace happens any time I add an option to the command line. Where should I be looking to make command line options work?

According to `gcloud --version`, I'm on gcloud SDK 0.9.69.

Comment: Google Cloud SDK 96.0.0 still does have the same issues.

Answer (score 2):

I got a response from Google support. It seems this exception is thrown when you try to create an SQL instance using a previously-used name. Adding some kind of uuid to the name will fix the issue.

(So my iterating my deployment code [ create-delete-create-delete-etc ] re-using the same name is the wrong way to handle things.)

Comment: I'm already using dynamically generated names and get this error anyway.